# What is the default GTK 3 Theme Engine in Ubuntu Unity?

Tags: themes, gtk

I was trying to install `ubuntu-desktop` package in `Ubuntu-Gnome(gnome shell)`. Using `unity-tweak` I set theme as `Ambiance`. But only `gtk2` applications are looking good. All `gtk3` application has ugly border(`header bar`) and background(sometimes). I have attached a screenshot.

What is the default `gtk3-theme-engine` in Ubuntu unity?

[image]

## Edit

if I run `gtk3 application` with root permission then theme is okay. I also created a new user but result is same.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think the gtk3-theme-engine is the one you are looking for. Anyway this is on fresh installed Ubuntu 14.04 machine:

```
$ locate theming-engines
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/3.0.0/theming-engines
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/3.0.0/theming-engines/libunico.so

$ dpkg -S /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/3.0.0/theming-engines/libunico.so
gtk3-engines-unico:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/3.0.0/theming-engines/libunico.so

$ apt-cache rdepends gtk3-engines-unico
gtk3-engines-unico
Reverse Depends:
  light-themes
  libgtk-3-0
```

References:

- [Gnome Developer: Theming changes](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-migrating-GtkStyleContext.html) for paths
- [Ubuntu Wiki: Theming - Decorations](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/Theming#Decorations) Switch to Gtk3 theming

It seems to me, a configuration problem.

- Check the environment variables by runing `env` look for `GTK_THEME`, `GTK_RC_FILES`, `GTK_CSD`.

  ```
  env | grep -i gtk
  ```
- Look if you have `gtkrc` in your home folder

  ```
  sudo find ~/ -iname gtkrc
  ```

`GTK_THEME` force Gtk3 application to use custom themes folder.

`GTK_RC_FILES` can change some Gtk3 theme settings/properties.

`GTK_CSD` tells Gtk3 to use Wayland Client Side Decoration, and default for Gtk3 application is to use the new header bar.

Well it was found by shantanu (OP):

> WOW, I found the culprit. `export GTK_CSD=1` was in `/etc/profile`. And
>   this variable was forcing gtk3 application to use CSD header.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This the output of env | gt.... GTK_MODULES=overlay-scrollbar:unity-gtk-module
GTK_CSD=1
GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus

Comment: I have created a new user with separate home folder. But no luck. That means there no local configuration problem exits. I didn't modify any theme file then why gtk3 application are not using compiz window-decorator? When I change something (like window decoration) only gtk2 applications reflect the changes.

Comment: This the output of gtkrc . /home/shantanu/.gimp-2.8/gtkrc
/home/shantanu/Documents/arc-theme/common/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
/home/shantanu/Documents/arc-theme/common/xfce-notify-4.0/gtkrc
/home/shantanu/Documents/csd-fix-resize-and-shadow/Ambiance-new/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
/home/shantanu/Documents/csd-fix-resize-and-shadow/Radiance-new/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
/home/shantanu/arc-theme/common/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
/home/shantanu/arc-theme/common/xfce-notify-4.0/gtkrc

Comment: WOW, I found the culprit.   export GTK_CSD=1 was in /etc/profile. And this variable was forcing gtk3 application to use CSD header.

Comment: @shantanu , What can I say. :) My self I did't give it any importance. It's new to me. Thank you. I will look for official reference to add it.

Answer (score 3):

My best guess is that the version of the Ambiance theme that is available is not fully compatible with the version of GTK+ that we ship.

It would probably be a lot easier for you and provide a better experience to use Ubuntu vanilla than to try to install Unity in elementary OS.

Answer (score 2):

I have got a partial solution. Using `gtk3-nocsd`, we can disable client side decoration. For Unity, we have to use this for an application separately. You cannot set it in environment. (i.e To fix `gnome-terminal`, edit `/usr/share/applications/gnome-terminal.desktop` and modify `Exec=` line as following)

```
EXEC=env LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/gtk3-nocsd/gtk3-nocsd.so gnome-terminal
```

## How to install gtk3-nocsd:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gtk3-nocsd
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use GTK, first change your display manager. Perform following operations.

```
sudo apt-get install gdm
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

You will get a screen like this...[image]

choose "gdm" using your cursor and then press enter.

Then you can restart the machine (optional), or just log out and login to "gnome-shell"

Therafter you can use "tweak-tool"

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Open the tweak-tool. Here you can choose whatever theme you may like, but make sure "Window" & "GTK+" has the same theme, else you will get the issue as you mentioned, that the window headers will be different.

I personally like [Vertex theme](https://github.com/horst3180/Vertex-theme). Try it out.. its quite brilliant,especially the dark one.
[image]

Comment: I don't think it's an answer but +1 for vertex theme suggestion.