# How can I enable the GTK3 header bars on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: unity, gnome, 16.04, gtk3

I want to see the applications like when running on Gnome 3 (with the buttons in the title bar):

[image: Gnome]

Instead of how I see them normally:

[image: Unity]

I can achieve what I want by running these commands before starting any application:

```
export GTK_CSD=1
export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME
```

---

I've tried to edit this file to make the changes permanent:

```
/usr/share/xsessions/ubuntu.desktop
```

In that file I change this:

```
DesktopNames=Unity
```

By this:

```
DesktopNames=GNOME
```

But then Unity will not start.

I'm finding a way of using the GTK3 header bars by default. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## For specific GTK3 apps

Edit their `.desktop` file (Nautilus' is located at `/usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop`)

And add `env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME` just after each `Exec=` line. For example, `nautilus.desktop`'s `Exec=` line(s) (It has two, one for opening a new window) will change from...

```
Exec=nautilus --new-window %U
[… Some other lines, skipping …]
Exec=nautilus --new-window
```

to

```
Exec=env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME nautilus --new-window %U
[… Some other lines, skipping …]
Exec=env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME nautilus --new-window
```

NOTE: If you use Unity, do the same to `/usr/share/applications/nautilus-autostart.desktop` and/or `/etc/xdg/autostart/nautilus-autostart.desktop`.

(You *may* have to logout/login.)

## For all GTK3 apps

**Word of warning: Telling *all* apps that the DE is GNOME *may* result in side effects.**

**Edit: Unity fails to start with this.**

Edit `~/.profile` and add a line:

```
export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME
```

then all apps will obey this.

Comment: I think that your solution for nautilus is wrong because it starts on boot. The file that I would edit is `/etc/xdg/autostart/nautilus-autostart.desktop`

Comment: Ironically, in Cinnamon, this causes the window manager to decorate the titlebars as headerbars!

Answer (score 4):

1. You can enable that by creating new file

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/profile.d/csd.sh
   ```
2. That contains

   ```
   export GTK_CSD=1
   export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity:GNOME

   #export GTK_THEME=Ambiance
   #export GTK_THEME=Adwaita:dark
   ```
3. Logout/Login

**Reference**: for the new colon format `Unity:GNOME`. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1554878

**Related question:** [What is the default GTK 3 Theme Engine in Ubuntu Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/653439/what-is-the-default-gtk-3-theme-engine-in-ubuntu-unity)

**Related page:** [A Fix For Black Corners Around CSD Windows in Ubuntu?](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/ubuntu-fix-black-corners-around-csd-windows)

### Tests:

- [Bharadwaj Raju's solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/780379/26246) is the best for now

  Using `/etc/profile..`

  ```
  export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME
  ```

  gnome-software OK, gnome-calculator OK, nautilus OK (black sharp corners, get smaller if killed then launched again), unity-control-center FAIL (No components, should run with `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity`)
- Mine (See above):

  gnome-software NO, gnome-calculator NO, nautilus OK (black sharp corners, get smaller if killed then launched again they go), unity-control-center NO.
- Another try with `export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=""`

  gnome-software OK, gnome-calculator OK, nautilus FAIL, unity-control-center FAIL.

Comment: Only working with Nautilus. Also, it has black corners on the top.

Comment: @Helio, Could you tell me names of other tools you are testing?

Comment: If you mean applications by tools, I tried gnome-calculator and gnome-softare also.

Comment: @Helio As far as I know the black corners are a Unity bug.

Comment: @BharadwajRaju: It seems like a unity bug...

Comment: `gnome-control-center` can be used as a replacement for `unity-control-center`, since the Unity one is basically a fork of the GNOME one.

Comment: @BharadwajRaju Yep, It does work.

Comment: Why GNOME Builder works perfectly with its header bars?

Comment: @Helio Does the black-corner issue occur with a different theme? Say, Arc? (I've seen Arc + Header bars + Unity work perfectly)

Comment: @Helio, All these seems weird to me, each application have different behavior to each of those environment variables.  In the XFCE calculator & softwares launch in CSD mode!  There should be a hidden trick some where.

Comment: @Sneetsher: Maybe the program overrides the environment variables. I'll wait until the header bars become standard.

Comment: @BharadwajRaju: Arc theme untested. Testing now...

Comment: @BharadwajRaju: With the Arc theme, the corners are not rounded, so the problem doesn't exist.

Comment: @Helio Strange, Arc was designed to have rounded corners. [Screenshot](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/4c0001cbfe222446c4b3af91027b716daec7d3d7/687474703a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f5068354f624f612e706e67)

Comment: @BharadwajRaju: The black corners also are shown with arc, but they are white. Seems like this can be solved restarting Nautilus. http://imgur.com/JqDO2VR

Answer (score 0):

Building off of user.dz, 
run

```
sudo nano /etc/profile.d/csd.sh
```

fill that with

```
export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME
```

and then

```
cd /usr/share/applications
sudo sed -i 's/Exec=/Exec=env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity:Unity7 /g' unity*
```

login out and back in

Alternatively, change only the currently installed apps to run in CSD mode,

```
sudo sed -i 's/Exec=/Exec=env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME /g' ^(?!unity).*$
```